# MySQL:How to show data from 1 column which separated by comma?

Tags: mysql, select, csv

Dear all, i want to show some data in one row from 1 column and also separated by comma.
if I do the regular `SELECT` method, it must be show as the long rows.

```
SELECT Serial_number FROM data

+-------------+
|Serial_number|
+-------------+
|0001         |
|0002         |
|0003         |
+-------------+ //and so on
```

How do i do to show result as:

```
+------------------------------+
|Serial_number                 |
+------------------------------+
|0001,0002,0003,....and so on  |
+------------------------------+
```

thanks for advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "*if I do the regular SELECT method, it must be show as the long rows*"?

Comment: @amosrivera: sorry if my question is unclear, i have edited my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Serial_number ) FROM data;
```

Note: GROUP_CONCAT has a maximum length.

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(col1, ',' , col2, .....) from tbl;
```

Comment: Think you meant field1 and field2 :P

Comment: yeah, sorry for that, now fixed :P

Comment: i'm just want to show data which separated by comma from 1 column. Not to show data from each column.

Comment: @klox can you give a sample of the result

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use something like phpmyadmin and save a select statement to file, then select csv as the file type..

Comment: I dont want to convert to CSV, just want to show data which separated by comma from one column.:-)

Comment: what are you using to interact with your db... php? a simpe select call does this, then implode with a comma..

Answer (score 0):

what you want is `GROUP_CONCAT()`

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Serial_number) FROM data
```

yields:

```
0001,0002,0003,...
```